# Dependent or independent samples?

Tags: statistics

For the scenario given below, I am confused about if the samples are dependent or independent since the scenario does not mention anything about the samples being paired/related or vice versa.

I am aware if terms such as paired, repeated measurements, within-subject effects, matched pairs, and pretest/posttest are instructed in scenarios then it indicates that the samples are dependent and the opposite applies to independent samples, but I am clueless for the given scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

*Alice and Bob work evening shifts in a supermarket. Alice has complained to
the manager that she works, on average, much more than Bob. The manager claims that on
average they both work the same amount of time, i.e. the competing claim is that the average
working hours are different. After a short discussion between the manager and Alice, the manager
randomly selected 50 evenings when Alice and Bob both worked.*

Comment: Samples are independent samples for the evenings when both work.  It says nothing about evenings when one of them is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you are describing seems to be setting up a hypothesis test, where the null hypothesis is $\mu_A=\mu_B$ and the alternative is $\mu_A\ne\mu_B$ , where $\mu_A$ ($\mu_B$) is the average number of hours worked by A (B).

It is given that the 50 days are "randomly selected". This usually means that the days are selected independently at random from the population of all available days where A and B both worked (though you have to wonder if the manager is going to allow a given day to be selected more than once).

By construction the pairs $(x_i,y_i),\ldots,(x_{50},y_{50})$ of hours worked by A and B are IID, which means you can conduct a paired test. The two individual samples $(x_1,\ldots,x_{50})$ and $(y_1,\ldots,y_{50})$ are not independent, since A's behavior can affect B's behavior and vice-versa, so you shouldn't perform a two-sample test (which anyhow would be less powerful than the paired test).

This whole scenario seems quite artificial to me, and a bad setting for illustrating a hypothesis test. When the manager looks only at days where both Alice and Bob are working (which we can reasonably assume is the only basis for Alice's complaint), the hypothesis being tested is specifically "on the days where both A and B are working, the average hours worked by A equals the average hours worked by B". It is possible, as @user2661923 mentions, that average hours differ on the days where only one of A and B are working, so the manager should be performing that test as well, and/or testing the global average hours on all days worked by A versus B.

Worst of all, if the manager has the power to randomly select from the population of all work days, why doesn't the manager simply summarize everything and report the population statistics? There's no need to drag a bizarre sampling ritual and a hypothesis test into this scenario at all.

Answer (score 0):

> After a short discussion between the manager and Alice, the manager randomly selected 50 evenings when Alice and Bob both worked.

Under what circumstances would the manager's approach be **invalid**?  Suppose that Alice normally works long hours, but on nights that Bob works, she is (hypothetically) so repulsed by Bob that she normally goes home early.  She compensates by working even more hours on the nights when Bob isn't there.

This would make the manager's analysis invalid, since the average number of hours that Alice works in an evening is not accurately reflected by the average number of hours that Alice works when Bob is also working.

Of course, the symmetrical argument is that Bob tries to work longer hours when Alice is also working because he likes being in the same building with Alice.

The fact that the manager chose the approach that he did **pre-supposes** that none of the above considerations apply.  This means that the manager is **assuming** that the average number of hours that Alice works is independent of whether Bob is also present.

The manager is **also assuming** that the average number of hours that Bob works is independent of whether Alice is also present.

**Addendum**

It occurs to me (well after the fact) that there is a subtle flaw in my conclusion.  It is (theoretically) possible for the strategy chosen by the manager to be valid, even when the average number of hours that Alice works is dependent on whether Bob is in the building.  Similarly, the strategy chosen by the manager can be valid, even when the average number of hours that Bob works is dependent on whether Alice is in the building.

Suppose (for example) that Alice and Bob find each other equally repulsive, and this causes each of them to shorten their typical work hours in equal measure, on the nights that they both work together.  In this scenario, the average number of hours that both Alice and Bob work are both dependent on whether the other person is in the building.

At the same time, under this artificial scenario, the strategy chosen by the manager should **still** provide an accurate assessment.  For example, suppose that on the nights that Alice and Bob both work, Alice works more hours.  Since it is assumed that Bob and Alice are each (typically) cutting back their hours when they are both present, **to the same degree**, then you can conclude that on the nights that only one of them is present, Alice's average work hours will **still** exceed Bob's average work hours.

Unfortunately, this is only the start of the analysis of when the manager's strategy may **still** be valid despite the assumption that the average number of hours that Alice and/or Bob work is dependent on the presence of the other person.

For example, suppose that Bob is indifferent to Alice's presence.  Further suppose that one of the days that Alice works with Bob is Saturday, when she goes home 1 hour early, and Bob does not.  Further suppose that Alice works (without Bob) on Thursday, typically working an extra hour.

Assuming that Alice and Bob each work 5 days a week, the dependence of Alice's work hours on Bob's presence will lower her average work hours per day by 0.2 hours (i.e. cause a **variance** of -0.2).  Following the manager's strategy, if the comparison between Alice's average work hours and Bob's average work hours is greater than the variance, then the manager will **automatically** still come to the right conclusion.

In a typical work setting, the strategy chosen by the manager seems typical (i.e. quick and easy).  No need for random sampling of work days of each of Alice and Bob (more work for the manager).  Instead, just use a quick and easy side by side comparison.

So, what the manager is **really** assuming is that whatever the **net** effect is on Alice's *variance* vs Bob's *variance* (if any) that is caused by Alice and Bob both working in the building on the same evening will either be

- less than the side by side comparison of their respective work hours
- or in the same direction as the side by side comparison of their work hours (i.e. if Alice works an hour more than Bob on the nights that they work together and if Alice's global average of work hours per day exceeds Bob's global average by only 0.2 hours).